# Performning Different Animation Based on a Button Click in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im currently designing an application in Ionic where I have a schedule for 5 days as an image. Now, I want to make a "detailed" view of each day that will fade in when one presses one out of 5 buttons, one for each day.

To do this, I use a CSS animation which pushes the image to the right a certain amount of pixels and then slides in two white images on top of the 4 days that shouldn't be visible.

My problem is that I have 5 animations, and I want to perform a different one depending on which of the 5 buttons is clicked. In angular, I can't do:

```
document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('animation', 'animation1 2s fade')
```

How would I go about passing the button information to CSS to perform these animations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Angular Web Animations API` to do what ever the animation you want. But keep in mind you must get the right version since Ionic is behind the Angular.

```
npm install @angular/animations@4.1.3 --save --save-exact
```

Here is the great [**article about basics o**](https://www.joshmorony.com/add-to-cart-with-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic/)f it with Ionic.